# SSRS multiple keyword search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I am using SSRS 2008. I have a report in which I would like the user to be able to enter any number of keywords in a search block to be checked against the dataset, regardless of the word position in the dataset. For example, if they search for 2005 Ford Escort, it should return all records which have all three words in the string, not necessarily in order as entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using dynamic SQL. If you have the ability to create your own functions, you can create a function that splits up your parameter input into different rows for each word entered (Note: each word MUST be separated by a Space for the function to work properly)

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
@returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @pos INT

WHILE CHARINDEX(' ', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(' ', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT '%' + CAST(@name AS VARCHAR(255)) + '%'

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
SELECT '%' + CAST(@stringToSplit AS VARCHAR(255)) + '%'

 RETURN
END
```

This will return 3 rows if you enter '2005 Ford Escape', 1 for each word separated by a Space. Now, you can create your query using dynamic SQL for the number of rows returned by the function, and the results would be what you would report off of.

(I'm sure that this dynamic SQL can be re-written to be cleaner, but the solution below will get you the answer/logic you need)

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query2 VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @query = ''
SET @query2 = ''

SELECT @query =
'
Select CarName from CarData
'
FROM dbo.SplitString('2005 Ford Escape')

SELECT @query2 = @query2 + 
'
and CarName like ''' + name + '''
'
FROM dbo.SplitString('2005 Ford Escape')

SET @query2 = STUFF(@query2,1,5,'where')

SET @query = @query + @query2
```

This will give you the following result if you execute:

```
PRINT @query
```

**Select CarName from CarData
where CarName like '%2005%'
and CarName like '%Ford%'
and CarName like '%Escape%'**

The last step is to create a table which you will report off of, and execute the @query variable into the table.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
CarName VARCHAR(250)
)

INSERT INTO #temp
EXEC(@query)

SELECT * FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: I added the function listed at the top. I created a Stored Procedure, but it is giving me an error on the line of: and VehicleInformation like ''' + name + '''. here is what i have used:

Comment: `PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_VehicleSearch] @SearchString as VarChar(MAX)
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
 DECLARE @query2 VARCHAR(MAX)

 SET @query = ''
 SET @query2 = ''

 SELECT @query = 
 '
 Select * from dbo.vwVehicles
 '
 FROM dbo.SplitString(@SearchString)

 SELECT @query2 = @query2 + 
 '
 and VehicleInformation like ''' + name + '''
 '
 FROM dbo.SplitString(@SearchString)

 SET @query2 = STUFF(@query2,1,5,'where')

 SET @query = @query + @query2
 
 CREATE TABLE #temp
 (
 CarName VARCHAR(250)
 )

 INSERT INTO #temp
 EXEC(@query)

 SELECT * FROM #temp

 DROP TABLE #temp

END`

Comment: Take out the 'END' at the end of the script. Also, your STUFF function should replace 4 characters, not 5. STUFF(@query2,1,4,'where'). A good way to check your work as you go is to PRINT @query, like I wrote above. It might be a good idea to generally read up on dynamic SQL so that you can become more comfortable experimenting with it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try to create a simple SQL query just like this

```
select * from Cars where CarBrand like '%' + @Name + '%'
```

this will display all data that matches the name of your keyword.

Comment: This reply works for a single keyword or string, but not breaking a string into multiple keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty simple solution. You can create a dynamic SQL string by replacing the spaces in the search string with a 'union select' string so each word in the search string gets a record in a table variable. Then just join the table variable to the car table:

```
-- load test data
declare @cars table(car varchar(50))
insert into @cars values
    ('Ford Escape 2005'),
    ('Ford 2005 Escape'),
    ('Escape 2005 Ford'),
    ('Escape Ford 2005'),
    ('2005 Ford Escape'),
    ('2005 Escape Ford'),
    ('Some 2005 Other Escape text Ford in here'),
    ('This is not the 2005 Ford you are looking for'),
    ('Neither is this Ford Escape with no Year')

-- get search string values into table
declare @search table(string varchar(50))
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @string nvarchar(50)
set @string = '2005 Ford Escape' -- this is your user parameter
set @sql = 'select ''' + replace(ltrim(rtrim(@string)),' ',''' union select ''') + ''''
insert into @search
exec(@sql)

-- return matching car records
select
    c.car
from @cars c
    inner join @search s
        on c.car like '%' + s.string + '%'
group by
    c.car
having count(*) = (select count(*) from @search) -- every search string record must match the car value
```